# How to convert time to 24 hour format in H2

Tags: sql, database, select, h2, date-formatting

Am trying to get current time in 24 hour format in H2 database but it doesn't seem to work I tried `select parsedatetime (current_time,'hh24:mm')` and select `parsedatetime (current_time,'HH24:mm')` and others ... but none seems to work

I tried to change the format of windows time but it didn't work also, I guess it's a windows problem, I've posted a question [windows not converting to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952339/windows-wont-change-time-to-24-hour-format)

Comment: @andrewnagyeb [tag:h2] and [tag:mysql] are two different [tag:rdmbs]s. This is not a dup, at least not to the question you linked to.

Comment: @Mureinik, Oh okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsedatetime` parses a string to a datetime. You should use `formatdatetime`:

```
SELECT FORMATDATETIME(current_time, 'HH:mm')
```